# Sending messages to Azure IotCentral via MQTT

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

I'm trying to work out how to open an MQTT connection from a device called 'test' to an Azure IoT Central instance, and send telemetry to a device identity registered with IoT Central. As I understand it, IoT Central is using IoTHubs under the hood, and so the Host field should look like: [iotcentralid].azure-devices.net, the username field should be: [iotcentralid].azure-devices.net:80/test/?api-version=2020-09-30&model-id=dtmi:com:example:Thermostat;1, and the password field should be a SAS token.

Whenever I try to connect with these details, I get a 'Connection refused: server unavailable' error from MQTT Explorer. I think the issue is that I'm building the SAS token wrong- I can see how to do it for an IoTHub, where I have access to thins like the Primary Connection String, but I can't tell how to do it for IoT Central.

Does anyone have any advice on how to generate a valid SAS token for IoT Central to send MQTT messages, or guidance on a better way I could do this?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to connect via MQTT Explorer to IoT Central. The hostname of the IoT Hub used under the hood for your IoT Central app is not based on the app id, instead it is some internal id. The trick is to connect first to IoT Central's DPS to register the device and obtain the URI of the assigned IoT Hub. With the URI you can generate the required SAS token to connect the MQTT client to the IoT Hub used by your IoT Central app.

Here are the required steps

1. Create an individual enrollment with symmetric key mechanism in IoT Central and take note of `{registration_id}, device's {primary_key}, {scope_id}`
2. Generate a **SAS token for DPS** with a script e.g, in [python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-sas?tabs=python#tabpanel_1_python), where 
   `uri = {scope_id}/registrations/{registration_id}` 
   `key = {primary_key} # from device details in IoT Central`
   `policy = 'registration'` and `expiry={long_enough_for_tests}`
3. Open MQTT Explorer and connect to IoT Central DPS as explained in the docs [Connect to DPS via MQTT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/iot-dps-mqtt-support) where 
   `cliend_id = {registration_id}` 
   `Username = {scope_id}/registrations/{registration_id}/?api-version=2019-03-31` 
   `Password = previously generated DPS SAS token`
4. After connecting, subscribing, and publishing to register the device you should finally receive a response containing the IoT Hub URI {iothub_hostname} to use.
5. Generate a new **SAS token for IoT Central** with a script e.g, in [python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-sas?tabs=python#tabpanel_1_python), where 
   `uri = {iothub_hostname}/devices/{device_id}` 
   `key = {primary_key} # from IoT Central` 
   `policy = None` and `expiry={long_enough_for_tests}`
6. Configure [MQTT Client to connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device) to IoT Central's IoT Hub as explained in the docs, where 
   `cliend_id = {device_id}` 
   `Username = {iothub_hostname}/{device_id}/?api-version=2018-06-30` 
   `Password = newly generated IoT Central SAS token` 
   and connect
7. Send device-2-cloud message by publishing to `devices/{device_id}/messages/events/` with message payloade e.g., `{'text_pl':'hello world!'}`
8. Check received message in IoT Central
   [snapshot of IoT Central Device Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEeja.png)